# How to load DevExpress report in Linux centos 7 with netcore

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, devexpress, centos7

When I run a devexpress report for mvc net core, it shows me a message that the libreia lib of linux centos 7 is missing

Answer (score 0):

1.Install DotNetCore

2.Install Dependencies by yum

```
yum install -y epel-release libunwind openssl libnghttp2 libidn krb5 libuuid lttng-ust zlib 
#This is most important:Install GDI+ on Linux
yum install -y libc6-dev libgdiplus
yum install -y curl cabextract xorg-x11-font-utils fontconfig
```

3.Flow instructions on this page:https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/119717/Create-End-User-Reporting-Applications/Web-Reporting/ASP-NET-Core-Reporting